# Variables will not convert to integers

Tags: excel, vba

Currently messing around with macros in excel. One that generates a range that fills 3 columns of cells with 1-9. 
Another that plots these numbers kind of like battle ship with x,y and v for the value.

I've gotten the number generation part working and I'm stuck on the plotting bit.

Currently the issue it that I'm getting an error "13" which means that my variables don't match up.
But i'm using a `CInt` to convert the variant to a `int`.
Debugging it seems like the for loop is getting all the values properly but just not converting.

Here is the code I have so far and a screenshot of the whole thing.

[image]

```
Sub random()
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim c As Integer, r As Integer
Set MyRange = Workbooks("test random gen").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G16:I30")
For c = 1 To MyRange.Columns.Count
For r = 1 To MyRange.Rows.Count
Randomize
MyRange.Cells(r, c) = Int((9 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
Next r
Next c
End Sub

Sub Button6_Click()
Dim Board As Range
Dim Table As Range
Dim c As Integer, r As Integer
Dim Xboard As Integer, Yboard As Integer, Vboard As Integer
Dim Xboardv As Variant, Yboardv As Variant, Vboardv As Variant

Set Table = Workbooks("test random gen").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G16:G30")
Set Board = Workbooks("test random gen").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("M16:U24")

For r = 1 To Table.Rows.Count
    Xboardv = Table.Cells.Value
    Yboardv = Table.Cells.Offset(columnOffset:=1).Value
    Vboardv = Table.Cells.Offset(columnOffset:=2).Value

    Xboard = CInt(Xboardv)
    Yboard = CInt(Yboardv)
    Vboard = CInt(Vboardv)

    Board.Cells(Xboard, Yboard).Value = (Vboard)

Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: What's the value that it's getting stuck on? Also you should probably use long not integer to avoid overflow errors.

Comment: Why do you declare `Xboardv`, etc. as `Variant`? Could just setting those as either `Integer`, `Long`, or `String` do the trick? Also, are there decimals, perhaps `Double` would work?

Comment: It is getting stuck on the ````Xboard = CInt(Xboardv)```` line with the error "13"

Comment: I tried to set ````XBoardv```` as integers but it was giving me errors that it wasn't the correct variable type. The only type that I believe it would accept for the ````Table.Cells.Value```` was variant but let me try different types.

Comment: Changing the `XBoardv` to anything else except variant causes the `XBoardv = Table.Cells.Value` line to break instead.

Comment: As I see it, `xboardv` has turned into an array sized `1 to 15, 1 to 1`. You would need to identify which index from your array you accessing. For example `Xboard = CInt(Xboardv(<X>,<Y>))`. Where in your case `<X>` holds any index from 1-15 and `<Y>` will always be 1. That being said. Not sure what you are trying to achieve here =)

Comment: And about the whole `Integer` data type. I would recommend just using `Long`

Comment: That did it but now it only does it for the first value of the array due to it being called out as (1,1)
`For r = 1 To Table.Rows.Count
    Xboardv = Table.Cells.Value
    Yboardv = Table.Cells.Offset(columnOffset:=1).Value
    Vboardv = Table.Cells.Offset(columnOffset:=2).Value
    
    Xboard = CInt(Xboardv(1, 1))
    Yboard = CInt(Yboardv(1, 1))
    Vboard = CInt(Vboardv(1, 1))

    Board.Cells(Xboard, Yboard).Value = (Vboard)

Next r`

How would I be able to iterate through those arrays?

Comment: Use a `For...Next` loop structure to iterate arrays.

Comment: So one loop to get the numbers, another to plot them

Comment: Without actually trying, maybe what you are after looks like: `Xboard = CInt(Xboardv(r,1))`

Comment: Oh my god that worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, oke I'll recap what I mentioned in my comments above:

---

> *"It is getting stuck on the Xboard = CInt(Xboardv) line with the error "13""*

You are creating an array of values with `Xboardv = Table.Cells.Value`. The array is sized `1 To 15, 1 To 1` and you need to use these index numbers as row and column parameters when you refer to any element in the array. So basically: `Xboard = CInt(Xboardv(<X>,<Y>))`.

> *"That did it but now it only does it for the first value of the array due to it being called out as (1,1)"*

That is because you are constantly refering to the same element. However, you have created a loop with `r` variable allready. So you can use that to call different elements: `Xboard = CInt(Xboardv(r,1))`

---

I've neglected the fact that your structure is somewhat strange and you are creating the same array in a loop. So move that outside your loop and possibly use a `For R = Lbound(Xboard) to Ubound(Xboard)` loop instead. And you can just address values without having to convert them too.

Btw, no need for `Integer` variables at all. Use `Long` instead.

Comment: Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

What's the reason for doing a conversion to begin with?
In cell 'D4', I've put the value 325, and I've run following piece of code:

```
Dim b As Integer

b = Range("D4").Value
```

Value `b` is 325, no problem. No conversion needed.

Comment: Yes you're are not wrong, I didn't need to convert the value.
I was just not calling out the value correctly.